# Unable to build bazel - Getting error running bazel with gin package

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-rules

I'm trying to add the gin package in the BUILD file. When I build the file I get the following error

***no such package '@com_github_gin_gonic_gin//go_default_library': The repository '@com_github_gin_gonic_gin' could not be resolved: Repository '@com_github_gin_gonic_gin' is not defined and referenced by***

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_library")
load("@bazel_gazelle//:def.bzl", "gazelle")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

go_library(
    name = "",
    srcs = [""],
    importpath = "",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@com_github_gin_gonic_gin//go_default_library",
        "@io_k8s_client_go//kubernetes",
        "@io_k8s_client_go//tools/clientcmd",
        "@io_k8s_client_go//util/homedir",
    ],
)
```

Comment: In your workspace file try calling go_rules_dependencies() first and then load other dependencies with respect to gin packages.

Answer (score 0):

In your workspace file try calling go_rules_dependencies() first and then load other dependencies with respect to gin packages.